# URL rewrite doesn’t work for magento

Tags: rewrite, magento

- Web Server Rewrites in admin is set to yes.
- Secure and unsecure URLs do not have index.php in them.
- mod-rewrite is enabled and works
- I tried all combination with RewriteBase / in htaccess
- Flushed cash more times than I can count (which has nothing to do with mod_rewrite but I still did)
- Re-indexed Catalog URL rewrites (same as above)[/b]

but it doesnt work :(

```
http://162.13.86.217/~useraccount/url.html

The requested URL /home/useraccount/domains/mydomain.com/public_html/index.php was not found on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
```

BUt index.php does exist and its located exactly at:
/home/useraccount/domains/mydomain.com/public_html/

I have the default htaccess file from magento on place and it works perfect on other server:

```
############################################
## rewrite everything else to index.php

    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [L]
```